# What does "Hidden due to privacy reasons" mean in Googe Play console 'App Vitals'?

Tags: android, google-play

Google has launched a section in play console called 'App Vitals'. Under this section a developer can see the diagnostic metrics like wakelocks held by the application.

There is a tab called 'By Wake Lock Tag' to sort the wake locks held by their tag. I see some entries whose tag is not visible instead I see the label 'Hidden due to privacy reasons'. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propably you see `_UNKNOWN` text, when app starts WakeLock one parameter is `tag`, this is app specific string, Google has stated that these are sensitive data. 
PowerManager sample code

```
mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "my custom tag");
mWakeLock.acquire();
...
mWakeLock.release();
```

`my custom tag` <- sensitive data by Google.

From help:

> For privacy purposes, partial wake lock identification tags are
>   anonymized

And from the [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakelock.html#fix_the_problem):

> Leave out any personally identifying information (PII) in the name,
>   such as an email address. Otherwise, the device logs _UNKNOWN instead
>   of the wake lock name.

Comment: The tag is _UNKNOWN, "Hidden due to privacy reasons" is actually the class acquiring the lock. Other examples are LocationListener and JobScheduler. Why would the class be sensitive? If this is a lock held by my code it certainly wouldn't need to be kept private from me.

Comment: In your app you may set this name for example with UserID, in that way you may identify the user - propably is main reason why google hides this info. Privacy policy says `data is collected anonymously`.

Comment: but again, why is the class name hidden?

Comment: Because you may enter name with, for example, user unique id, google hides this name because in privacy policy has info "data will be collected anonymously", when you put UUID in wake lock tag you may identify user.

Comment: I think you are missing my point. I'm referring to the class name not the tag. My classes are not named with user information... In fact, my tags also do not contain user information. So there must be another reason, or they are wakelocks not acquired by my code.